# QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat::toImage() Android black image

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es

I'm trying the code from https://dangelog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/using-fbos-instead-of-pbuffers-in-qt-5-2/ on an Android device.

After some changes to get the code running without errors, I can't get a correct image yet. On Android the image is completely black. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Here the changes in the first lines:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion(2);
format.setMinorVersion(2);

QOffscreenSurface window;
//window.setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
window.setFormat(format);
window.create();

QOpenGLContext* context=(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());

// context.setFormat(format);
/* if (!context.create())
    qFatal("Cannot create the requested OpenGL context!");
*/
context->makeCurrent(&window);

const QRect drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
const QSize drawRectSize = drawRect.size();

QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat fboFormat;
//fboFormat.setSamples(16);
//fboFormat.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);

QOpenGLFramebufferObject fbo(drawRectSize, fboFormat);
fbo.bind();
```

**Update 1**
I changed the code into

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion(3);
format.setMinorVersion(0);

char* extensionList = (char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION);
qDebug()<<extensionList;
QOffscreenSurface window;
//QOffscreen is always an OpenGLSurface 
//window.setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface); 
window.setFormat(format);
window.create();

//QOpenGLContext* context=(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());

QOpenGLContext context;
context.setFormat(format);
if (!context.create())
    qFatal("Cannot create the requested OpenGL context!");

if(!context.makeCurrent(&window))
    qFatal("Cannot makecurrent(windows)!");
```

But it doesn't change the result...I still get a black png image. I check the format of the Qimage and it seems to be correct (ARG32, which corresponds to the format of the fbo GL_RGBA).

Comment: Not sure if this is the main problem, but 2.2 is not a valid OpenGL version. OpenGL 2.2 never existed, the version following 2.1 was 3.0.

Comment: The code you commented out seems crucial (context creation etc., setting format and surface types). Why did you comment it out? Also there's a couple of calls where you don't check the return values for errors, such as makeCurrent() and bind()

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solve the problem....

Comment: Could you please provide *more* code? There are several things that might go wrong.